# How can I call an R script from a Python script using 'subprocess' module?

Tags: python, r, subprocess

I found the link below which explains the procedure to implement subprocess module. Specifically, I wanted to call an R script from a python script. But, it is throwing file not found error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Here is the website link: https://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa/

The code that I tried to implement based on the website is as follows:

**Sample R Script**

*max.R*

Fetch command line arguments

`myArgs <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)`

Convert to numerics

`nums = as.numeric(myArgs)`

cat will write the result to the stdout stream

`cat(max(nums))`

**Sample Python Script**

*run_max.py*

`import subprocess`

Define command and arguments

`command = 'Rscript' path2script = 'path/to your script/max.R'`

Variable number of args in a list

`args = ['11', '3', '9', '42']`

Build subprocess command

`cmd = [command, path2script] + args`

check_output will run the command and store to result

`x = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)`

`print('The maximum of the numbers is:', x)`

I also changed the cmd variable below in Python script another website but it didn't work:

`cmd = ['C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/Rscript', '--vanilla', './max.R', '11','3','9','42']`

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the max.R script on your computer, that is what is causing the file not found error. Where is max.R located?

Comment: I tried that  too but it is still not working. I have just made it relative to the current path from which I am running the code. It is not because of the path. I have read other files that are in the same folder and I am able to read them. @JamesSteele

Comment: Figured the solution. I need to provide the complete of Rscript.exe (R interpretor). It is located  under bin folder. C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/bin/Rscript.